# CheckTie function in Java Tic-tac-toe not functioning

Tags: java

So i'm having issues with getting my CheckTie method working, i've tried using boolean to get it working but it just announces that there's a tie when I press the first button. I do have a method that checks if the game board is full but it seems to be some issues when I try to have my view class implement it.

It shows the winners correctly atleast.

What am I doing wrong with the checkTie method?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Observable;
import java.util.Observer;

public class Model extends Observable implements ModelInterface {
private int[][] board = new int[3][3];

private int player;
private List<Observer> observers;
private char winner;
private boolean tie;

public Model(){

    player =1;
    this.observers=new ArrayList<>();      
    reset();
}
public int [][] getBoard(){
    return board;
}


@Override
public void movePlayer(String input) {
    int tmp = Integer.parseInt(input);  
    int x = tmp %3;
    int y = tmp /3;
    updateBoard(x,y);
    checkWin();
    checkTie();
}
private void updateBoard(int x, int y) {
    if ( board[x][y] == 0){
        board[x][y] = player;
        if (player == 1)
            player = 2;
        else
            player = 1;
    }
    this.setChanged();
    this.notifyObservers(this);
}
private void checkWin(){

    if(board[0][0] != 0 && board[0][0] == board[1][1] && board[1][1] == board[2][2]){
        winnerFound(board[0][0]);
    }
    else if(board[0][2] != 0 && board[0][2] == board[1][1] && board[1][1] == board[2][0]){
        winnerFound(board[0][2]);
    }
    else{
        for(int i = 0; i <3; i++){
            if(board[i][0] != 0 && board[i][0] == board[i][1] && board[i][1] == board[i][2]){
                winnerFound(board[i][0]);
                break;
            }
            if(board[0][i] != 0 && board[0][i] == board[1][i] && board[1][i] == board[2][i]){
                winnerFound(board[0][i]);
                break;

            }             
        }
    }


}


private void winnerFound(int board){
    this.winner= (char) board;
    reset();


}

private boolean checkTie(){
    boolean tie = true;
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
            if(board[i][j] == 0)
            {


                tie = true;
            }

        }
    }
    return tie;
}


public int isThereAWinner() {
    if (winner ==1)
        return 1;
    return winner;

}


public boolean isThereATie() {

    if (tie = false)    
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}



@Override
public void register(Observer obj) {
    if (obj == null) throw new NullPointerException();
    if(!observers.contains(obj)) observers.add(obj);

}



private void reset() {
    //        for(JButton label : board){
        //            label.setText("");
        //        }
    //        panel.repaint();
    setChanged();
    this.notifyObservers();
}
@Override
public void unregister(Observer obj) {
}

@Override
public Object getUpdate(Observer obj) {
    return null;
}

}
```

And here's the view class:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Observable;
import java.util.Observer;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.ListSelectionModel;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class View extends JFrame implements  ViewInterface, Observer {
Controller controller;
JPanel panel;
ArrayList<JButton> board = new ArrayList(); 
JPanel messagePanel;
JLabel topText;
JPanel sidePanel;
JPanel westPanel;
JTextField Spelare;
JButton LäggTill, Exit;
JButton test;
JList lista;
DefaultListModel model;         //Lista för spelare
//private String letter = " ";

//    private int count = 0;
//    private char winner;

public View(Controller controller){
    super();
    this.controller = controller;
    setupUI();
}

private void setupUI(){
    setupFrame();
    setupMessagePanel();
    setupPanel();

    setupBoard();
    setupPlayers();
    setupLäggTill();

    this.getContentPane().add(panel);
}

private void setupFrame(){
    setSize(400,400);
    setTitle("Tic-Tac-Toe");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
}

private void setupMessagePanel(){
    messagePanel = new JPanel();
    topText = new JLabel("X startar");
    messagePanel.add(topText);
    this.getContentPane().add(messagePanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
}

private void setupPlayers(){
    sidePanel = new JPanel();
    westPanel = new JPanel();
    Spelare = new JTextField("Skriv ditt namn", 9);
    Spelare.addActionListener(controller);
    model = new DefaultListModel();     //DefaultListModel för att lägga till personer
    lista = new JList(model);
    lista.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
    lista.setLayoutOrientation(JList.VERTICAL);
    lista.setVisibleRowCount(7);

    lista.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50,200));

    sidePanel.add(Spelare);
    westPanel.add(lista);

    this.getContentPane().add(sidePanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    this.getContentPane().add(westPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
}



private void setupLäggTill()
{
    LäggTill = new JButton("Lägg till");
    Exit = new JButton("Exit");
    LäggTill.setActionCommand("Lägg till");
    LäggTill.addActionListener(controller);
    Exit.setActionCommand("Exit");
    Exit.addActionListener(controller);
    sidePanel.add(LäggTill);
    messagePanel.add(Exit);

    this.getContentPane().add(sidePanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

}
private void setupPanel(){
    panel = new JPanel();


    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 3, -1, -1));
}

private void setupBoard(){    
    for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++){
        JButton symbol = new JButton();
        symbol.setText("");
        symbol.setSize(new Dimension(400/3,400/3));
        symbol.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        symbol.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(2, 2, 2, 2,Color.RED));


        symbol.addActionListener(controller);
        symbol.setActionCommand(String.valueOf(i));
        board.add(symbol);
        panel.add(symbol);


    }
}


@Override
public void gameTie() {

    giveMessage("Oavgjort", "Otur, ingen vann");
    reset();

}

@Override
public void gameWon(char winner) {

    giveMessage("Spel klart", winner + " vann!");
    reset();
}

private void giveMessage(String header, String message){

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,
            message,
            header,
            JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

}

private void reset() {
    for(JButton label : board){
        label.setText("");
    }
    panel.repaint();
}

public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
    Model model_copy = (Model)o;
    int[][] test = model_copy.getBoard();
    int winner = model_copy.isThereAWinner();
    boolean tie  = model_copy.isThereATie();

    int index = 0;
    for (int i =  0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            if(test[j][i] == 1)
            {
                this.board.get(index).setText("X");

            }
            else  if (test[j][i] == 2)
            {

                this.board.get(index).setText("O");
            }
            //              else if(test[j][i]==3)
            //              {
            //                  this.board.get(index).setEnabled(false);
            //              }
            index ++;
        }
    }



    if (winner ==1)
    {
        giveMessage("Spel klart", "X" + " vann!");
        reset();

    }
    else if (winner ==2)
    {
        giveMessage("Spel klart", "O" + " vann!");
        reset();
    }
    else if (tie ==false)
    {
        giveMessage("Oavgjort", "Otur, ingen vann");
    }

}  

}
```

Comment: This is not a debugging service.

Answer (score 1):

Your condition must be the following. Otherwise, there is always a tie since you're always returning `true`. If we still have a cell with `0`, it means the game is not over yet and it can't be a tie.

```
if(board[i][j] == 0) {
    tie = false;
}
```

---

```
private boolean checkTie(){
    boolean tie = true;
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
            if(board[i][j] == 0) {
                tie = false;
            }

        }
    }
    return tie;
}
```

Comment: I tried that but it still doesn't give me the popup message that states that there is a tie

Comment: @HousePlant Well that is just one problem of the equation that is solved. Now you have to come up with an algorithm that checks that there isn't a winner. If there is no winner, there is a tie.

Comment: Oh alright, well thanks for solving that part of the issue for me then! Really been scratching my head over that one!